# How to provide gRPC server in .net Framework application?

Tags: c#, grpc, .net-4.8

Grpc.Core will be deprecated soon, so how to provide gRPC server in .net Framework application in the future?

Comment: Ideally, you should migrate to a newer framework (e.g. .NET 5) if at all possible (and use the grpc-dotnet server based on AspNetCore). Otherwise, there is currently no other way of starting a server on the legacy .NET Framework than using Grpc.Core. Currently, it is still the plan to deprecate Grpc.Core, but stay tuned for updates.

Comment: Thanks, we have a huge code base with a lot of challenges before being able to move to .Net 5